# How to merge Object in Salesforce using node js

Tags: node.js

I am looking for options about how to merge the SObject using node js. I have been using JSForce node module for connecting and doing other actions using the same module but i don't find anything related to merging. Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Thanks,
Janakiram.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: I am trying to do a merge operations against Salesforce using a JSForce node module.  I am checking for those options.